# invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /container/tdarr-server/server

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I am trying to use an nfs share to use docker swarm with a single endpoint server for a drive, the NFS share its self does work as i can create files on it, however when trying to use it on a stack i get a bind source path error. my nfs share is set to /container on both machines so each machine can find it at the same location. here is what i have as a volume in my docker compose file:

```
    volumes:
  - /container/tdarr-server/server:/app/server
  - /container/tdarr-server/configs:/app/configs
  - /container/tdarr-server/logs:/app/logs
  - /container/plex/media:/media
  - /container/tdarr-server/transcode:/transcode
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this:

On each server mount a nfs share. Assuming you have a nfs server sharing a volume "docker_volumes" you could mount that as "/mnt/volumes"

Then your stack file could look like this:

```yaml
version: "3.9"

volumes:
  prometheus:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      o: bind
      type: none
      device: /mnt/volumes/prometheus-data

services:
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:latest
    volumes:
    - prometheus:/data
```

NB. Docker will NOT create missing volumes for you. Each missing directory (e.g. `./prometheus-data`) needs to be manually created on the nfs share before docker will start the service.

As an alternative you can - rather than pre-mounting the nfs volume in a defined location - provide docker with the nfs connection details so it can mount the nfs share on the fly:

```yaml
volumes:
  data:
    driver_opts:
      type: "nfs"
      o: "addr=10.40.0.199,nolock,soft,rw"
      device: ":/docker/example"
```

Again, if you provide a path into the nfs share as part of the device description, docker will not create it if it does not exist. The admin must pre-create any specific sub folders referenced before services or containers will be able to use the volume definition.